# in ruby I need one back slash but it gives me three

Tags: ruby, backslash

I wonder why the back slash '\' doesn't work well.

```
@hash["zebra"] = "African land animal with stripes"
@hash["fish"] = "aquatic animal"
@hash["apple"] = "fruit"

def printable
    hashs = @hash
    words = Array.new
    hashs.each {|key, value|
        word = '['+key+'] '+  '\\"' + value +'\\"\\n'
        words << word
    }
    words.sort.join("")

end
```

I expect 
**"[apple] \"fruit\"\n[fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n[zebra] \"African land animal with stripes\""**

but what I got was
**"[apple] \\"fruit\\"\n[fish] \\"aquatic animal\\"\n[zebra] \\"African land animal with stripes\\"\n"**

so it gives me three back slash instead of one. why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting what you want: `puts printable #=> [apple] \"fruit\"\n[fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n[zebra] \"African land animal with stripes\"\n`? The first two of three backslashes is a single backslash character; the third backslash escapes the following character.

Comment: yes.. i don't know why it doesn't work TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby, the content in single quote is be a pure string no special function, so you need to change the content when use single quote, or you will use the better way that use double quote is more correct ruby style

```
@hash = Hash.new
@hash["zebra"] = "African land animal with stripes"
@hash["fish"] = "aquatic animal"
@hash["apple"] = "fruit"

def printable
    hashs = @hash
    words = Array.new
    hashs.each {|key, value|
        word = '['+key+'] '+  '"' + value +'"'+"\n" #use single quote
        word = "["+key+"] "+  "\"" + value +"\"\n" #use double quote
        words << word
    }
    words.sort.join("")
    puts words
end
```

Comment: thank you! I tried and it works. one thing is that I just realized that I need to get rid of the last 'n'. so what i need after Value is that    \"\ . but when I tried "\"\" it even doesn't run... if I wanna add only  \"\  at the end, how should i change?

Comment: ＠gin85, "\"\\", I think you should learn to know what's different between double quote and single quote

Comment: I tried "\"\\" , but it adds two back slash at the end instead of one... I learned like if two back slash are together, later one is escaped, but it doesn't work..

Comment: `word = "["+key+"] "+  "\"" + value +"\"\\"` do you write this?, it must can work and puts  [zebra] "African land animal with stripes"\

Comment: I agree with you that it should work, I just don't get it why it doesn't.. anyway, thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because some characters need to escapes when they are in double quote `"` and here the some list of them:

\" – double quote (")

\ – single backslash ()

\a – bell/alert (plays a tone)

\b – backspace (removes previous character, shifts cursor back one position)

\r – carriage return (moves cursor to beginning of line)

\n – newline (moves cursor to next line)

\s – space ( )

\t – tab (  )

Comment: Or in other words with single quotes (`'\n'`) jus means backslash n, but in double quotes (`"\n"`) is an escape character replaced with a newline.